# How to down tune power consumption on laptop home server

Tags: power-management

I recently got a new laptop, so I decided to use my old one as a home server. The problem is that it's rather power-hungry and I would like to make it more energy-efficient.

Would it be a good idea to turn off or disable most of the power of the GPU? How would I do this? Are there any other options?

specification

Graphics car: Nvidia geforce GT 560m 3gb 
Laptop Model: Asus G74s 
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Not sure about optimus. i Just wiped windows and clean installed Ubuntu

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about this computer? Does it have an *Optimus* configuration? What kind of graphics card? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/657536/edit) this in to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for;

http://www.linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

TLP is a power management tool for Linux. It brings you the benefits of advanced power management without the need to understand every technical detail.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

Run PowerTOP before & after to see difference. Power settings will be re-profiled by TLP upon fresh boot.